# In Rails 3.2.8 how do I add a background image to all my views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add a background image to all my views, how do I do it?

- please show code example
- THE ANSWER IS:

  body{
      background-image:url('/assets/myimage.jpeg');
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, at least in my 'localhost' environment:

```
body { 
background-image: url(image_path('photobackground.jpg'));
background-size: cover;
```

}

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just put your files in  "app/assets/images/" and in your view you have to use:

```
<%= image_path "exemple.png" %>
```

Or you can directly generate img tag with:

```
<%= image_tag "exemple.png" %>
```

Comment: but how do I make it a background image?

Comment: In your CSS, with something like "background-image: url(<%= image_path "exemple.png" %>);" and your css name file must end with *.css.erb or *css.scss

Comment: in which file should I write that?

Comment: You have a folder app/assets/stylesheets for your css file, but if you have never use css and html you have to practice in a static page before start ruby on rails.

Comment: should I put it in application.css

Comment: Yes, you can but not just  "background-image: url(<%= image_path "exemple.png" %>);"

Comment: You have to write css code but if you don't know css learn it.

Comment: dude, This site is for questions, and if Im asking, it means I dont know... so telling me to learn css is useless...... and Im talking about RAILS....

Comment: But set background image in all your views depend of your css. Or i forget, you can write <%= image_tag "exemple.png" %> in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb but it's not the proper way and it just put image in all views, not a background image.